# How to build assetBundle without using Selection

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to write my own editor that would allow me to search the whole Assets folder for object type of X and make an AssetBundle from them.

I went through all the manuals and docs and it seems that they all use the Selection class to build the Assets Bundle.

But what if there are 10 000+ objects scattered in different folders and I don't want to select each manually, yet I still want to track their dependencies. Is there a way to do so?

I have already tried editing Selection.objects, but as much as I understand it's limited to one concrete scene.

Is it possible to skip the whole Selection class and just use BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle() method? If yes, how to get the correct list of objects that can be used? Do I need to write my own deep threading loop to get the dependencies?

Comment: You could also use uTomate to build asset bundles. UTomate's build asset bundle action has a wildcard based selection that allows you to select assets of a certain type within your project. This kind of selection is also resilient against changes in the project structure. For example, you could type something like "**/*.prefab" to select all prefabs in your project and build an asset bundle from them. This approach will also work for textures materials, etc. Check http://www.ancientlightstudios.com/utomate/documentation/actiondocs/build_asset_bundle.html for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a list of objects. That's it. How you get them is irrelevant. You can do that with the Selection class, but if you have other means of finding the assets, that's no problem either.

As for dependencies, keep in mind that your final call will be something like:

```c#
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle(main_asset, objects_array, path, BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies | BuildAssetBundleOptions.CompleteAssets);
```

See that [`BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildAssetBundleOptions.CollectDependencies.html)? It will make sure that all the necessary dependencies for the objects you've specified get included as well.

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to get object that are, for example, 3d meshes? I tried AssetDatabase.FindAssets, but I'm not sure how to get the objects from the array of strings. How should I load/instantiate them?

Comment: A call to FindAssets will return the GUIDs of the assets it finds. Those are easily translated to actual paths calling GUIDToAssetPath and those you can load using LoadAssetAtPath, from the top of my head. Give that a go, and if it doesn't work, perhaps that might make for a new question.

Comment: That works great, thank you! I just need to figure out how to exclude scenes when I do the FindAssets with a filter for type Object.

Comment: Hi, @CreativeMagic , I am also stuck in the same situation that you were in. Have you had a chance to get the solution? Because when i try to load all the assets from the path, I get the size of the array as 0. Am i doing something incorrect??

UnityEngine.Object[] mAssets = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath ("Assets/ForExport/");

Comment: @user1683989 the answer is literally in the comments above you :) LoadAllAssetsAtPath() will return you only the list of GUIDs so you need to use GUIDToAssetPath() on them to get an actual list of URLs, otherwise it might cast into null and you'll get 0 length arrays. If that doesn't help - try making a new question where someone will answer in more detail ;)

Comment: @CreativeMagic I am getting the size of the object array as zero. I know I am somewhere close but i am failing to understand why the size of the array is zero.

Comment: @user1683989 try Debug.Log( AssetDatabase.FindAssets().Lenght) without assigning it to the object. If it's still zero than you need to start a new question. If it's not, then you lose data because of casting.

Comment: @CreativeMagic I think i have found it but with
string dPath = "Assets/ForExport";
AssetDatabase.FindAssets("",new string[]{dPath});
As you can see here, it takes two arguments. Passing it these prints the same object GUI multiple times because i have a prefab here. So I need to add a label i think.

Comment: @CreativeMagic hey, i have finally fixed it. thanks for the help. Cheers